# Use of operator 'and' Jess

Tags: operators, jess

How do I use correctly the operator 'and' in Jess?

Example of my (wrong) code:

```
(test (and (>= ?x ?minx) (and (<= ?x ?maxx) (and (>= (+ ?x (- ?y1 ?y)) ?minx) (and (<= (+ ?x (- ?y1 ?y)) ?maxx) ...
```

Also, in a if clause, how to use that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I added some indents to your code to try to understand what you're doing:

```
(test
    (and (>= ?x ?minx)
         (and (<= ?x ?maxx)
              (and (>= (+ ?x (- ?y1 ?y)) ?minx)
                   (and (<= (+ ?x (- ?y1 ?y)) ?maxx)
```

There are missing ")"s at the end but I'll assume that's not the issue. Basically, if you're trying to express the conjunction of a bunch of conditions, you just need one `and`, and give it as many arguments as you need. So, for example, something like

```
(test
    (and (>= ?x ?minx)
         (<= ?x ?maxx)
         (>= (+ ?x (- ?y1 ?y)) ?minx)
         (<= (+ ?x (- ?y1 ?y)) ?maxx)))
```

As far as `if` goes, it's pretty clearly documented in [the manual](http://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/71/functions.html#if):

```
(if (> ?x 100) then
    (printout t "X is big" crlf)
 elif (> ?x 50) then
    (printout t "X is average" crlf)
 else
    (printout t "X is small" crlf))
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!